# Permutations, combinations, and the multiplication principle for counting

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A catering service offers 12 appetizers, 9 main courses, and 6 desserts. A customer is to select 5 appetizers, 3 main courses, and 4 desserts for a banquet. In how many ways can this be done?

Comment: I would say - combinations and the multiplication principle.

Answer (score 0):

I am still new to this topic, but I think it is solved by

Appetizers = $ 12\choose{5}$ = 792

Main course = $ 9\choose{3}$ = 84

Dessert = $ 6\choose{4}$ = 15

I hope this helps I am not sure if I am right.

---

Based on the comment below, you multiply them. I think it is because of multiplication rule "and" .

So the answer becomes 792 * 84 * 15 = 997,920.

Comment: You multiply the choices, rather than adding them.

Comment: Your answer would be clearer if you removed your original incorrect attempt.